# swirling hexagon

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can someone show me how to use tikz to produce a "swirling hexagon" using grey-scale to differentiate triangles at distinct arms of the spiral pattern?
A figure for this pattern can be found googling "swirling hexagon".

Comment: You even want us to google it. That's new.

Comment: -1 from me, this really is a new low. At the very least, add an image of the thing you want us to create from scratch

Comment: I find [this picture](http://cdn.interweavestore.com/media/catalog/product/cache/35/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/E/P/EP10654.jpg): is this what you want? A well deserved downvote, sorry.

Comment: @egreg That's the girl I mentioned in a comment in my answer. Could you draw her?

Comment: Pretty, by the way.

Comment: @runartrollet With picture mode, perhaps.

Comment: Anyway, J.M.Stern, Welcome to Tex.SE. You will find that if you post questions here which shows some effort, either into doing a bit a research, or telling us what you have already tried, you will get serious answers. Post and [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), and a picture which shows what you want us to do. Make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Is http://texample.net/tikz/examples/rotated-polygons/ the sort of thing you have in mind?

Comment: I sincerely hope that upon closing, this post and the answers it spawned do not go away completely :) That extremely dry humor by percusse, as the first comment, and the slapstick that occurred in the answer that was not accepted, really should be preserved somehow as an example of TeX.SE humor.

Comment: @egreg and friends: run this and have fun: `wget https://gist.github.com/cereda/50ff43abec5d7f1c23d92d23b7223140/raw/swirling-hexagon.tex; pdflatex swirling-hexagon.tex` It's a swirling hexagon, I guess... `:)`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Is this what you wanted? Please at least include an image of what you want to achieve next time. It's understandable that not everyone knows how to produce a starting code, but make our job easier by providing as much help as you can.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc, shapes}

\tikzset{
    box/.style={
        regular polygon,
        regular polygon sides=6,
        minimum size=1cm,
        inner sep=0mm,
        outer sep=0mm,
        rotate=90,
        draw
    }
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \x [
    evaluate=\x as \grad using int(100-(\x*15)),
    evaluate=\x as \deg using int(\x*60)
    ] in {1,...,6}{
    \coordinate (n\x) at ({90+60*\x}:5mm);
    \begin{scope}[rotate=\deg]
    \fill[black!\grad] (0,0) --++ (150:5mm) --++ (210:5mm) --++ (270:1cm) --++ (330:1.5cm) --++ (390:1.5cm) --++ (90:5mm) --++ (210:1.5cm) --++ (150:1cm) --++ (90:5mm) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
    \draw (0,0) -- ({90+60*\x}:5mm);
}
\node[box] at (0,0) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: not swirly enough. the OP wants it swirly, you know... :D ;) (joke aside. I like it.)

Comment: @naphaneal :D This is the only "swirling hexagon" that made sense to me.

Comment: +1 for even helping the last of us (with the least amount of information given)!

Answer (score 20):

This question really is too vague. At least attach an image of what you want. Googling the image returns many very different results, and different depending on who is searching. I found the following picture:

[image]

So I created this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [fill=green] (0,0) -- (2,0) -- (1,1.5) -- cycle;
\draw [fill=green] (3,0) rectangle (4,3);
\draw [fill=green] (5,0) rectangle (6,5);
\draw [fill=green] (7,0) rectangle (8,5);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's a triangle, not a hexagon. :P

Comment: well, google gave me this, and a girl in a sweater, among other things.  Should i draw the girl? I'm confused. Better lie down.

Comment: You have to truncate the triangle to get an hexagon. Observe that image closer. lol

Comment: @runartrollet: The `tikz force` is strong in you ;-)

Comment: Yeah, I see that now. Guess my answer won't be accepted after all. *sigh*

Comment: Disappointed.  Insufficient swirling.  Pls more swirling.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine Some would even settle for "more cowbell."  Did I mention, you can google it.

Comment: This is sincerely hilarious.  +1 for making me smile! If I could accept it as _the answer_ I would.